# How to sync records with ETL to a datawarehouse in NRT

Tags: mysql, pentaho, etl

I am a newbie with all these ETL stuff,
I wonder what are the best solutions with tools like PDI (pentaho data integration) to sync some records from operational databases to datawarehouse

I am in a near real time context (so I don't want to sync data 1 a day but every 5 minutes for example.)

3 ways immediately come to me:

- using an indexed time columns on operation database
  Ex: SELECT * FROM records WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTES

but I can still miss some records or having some duplicates etc...

- using a table or a sync column
  Ex: SELECT * FROM records WHERE synced = no
- using a queue service
  Ex: at record creation, creating an event in a rabbitMq (or any other tool) telling that something is ready to get sync

Comment: The queue is a good idea, but you might also want to consider replication. In terms of PDI you could use a high watermark incremental extract. Meaning store the highest date/time you extracted on the last run, then on the next select everything newer than that and then store the new date/time.

Comment: Seems a good idea. But it could be nice to work with a  "ready_to_sync_date" field on the source database. Once a record is ready to be sync (all foreigns tables have been inserted, the record state is not going to change anymore...) set the ready_to_sync_field to current date.

If i need to sync an existing record again (maybe an update on the source record happened and context changed) just overwriting the date field with a more recent one could be use to sync again the existing record